# Css issue position

Tags: html, css

This is the html part :

```
<div class="sama_productblocks_grid">
    <div class="title-bar">
        <h3>Nieuwste producten</h3>
    </div>
.....
</div>
```

This is the css

```
 .sama_productblocks_grid .title-bar h3 {
     margin: 0;
     position: relative;z-index: 3;
     font-size:18px;
     display: inline-block;
     color: #6D6C6C;
     font-weight: 400;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif !important;
     padding: 0px 65px;
}
/*newest product*/
.title-bar{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    z-index: 3;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sama_productblocks_descrition {margin-top:40px;}
```

What i want to achieve is to put a line before and after the text: `Nieuwste producten`. So I want to look like this: 
`-----------    Nieuwste producten     ------------`

Comment: please add your code to fiddle

Comment: Try `.title-bar h3:before,.title-bar h3:after{
    content:"----------------------";
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.hr-div {
    height: 1px; 
    background-color: #e6e6e7; 
    text-align: center;  
    margin: 10px 0 10px -10px;
}
.hr-span {
    background-color: white; 
    position: relative; 
    top: -10px; 
    padding:0 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="hr-div">
    <span class="hr-span">Your Title Here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
h3:before {
    content: "---------------- "
}
h3:after {
    content: " ----------------"
}
```